# What's the best way to style the default virtual directory listing in SSRS?

Tags: css, reporting-services, virtual-directory, reportserver

I have SSRS 2008 R2 installed with a custom security sublayer.  When logging into the client side area of SSRS via the /ReportServer url, SSRS returns a basic virtual directory listing as seen here:

[image: SSRS Virtual Directory Listing]
Obviously this looks rubbish for a client to see, but I'm currently at a loss for how to tart it up and apply my own branding and styling to it.  How do I add header and footer images, other standard navigation, css etc to make it look like our corporate website?

Suggestions gratefully received, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual server page is not meant to be changed...you want to go to `http://yourURL/Reports` and change the actual report manager.  The report manager has a CSS file that can be modified.

Report manager style sheet is available in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply JonH.  I was under the impression that /Reports was the admin interface, and /ReportServer was the user facing interface. Is that not so?  Is the /Reports interface intended to be opened up to the www?

Comment: No the report manager is for admins / users.  Remember you control what the users see via the security of the report schema.  In addition, if you do not want a user to be an admin specify it in the security of the site.  The reportserver is simply a sort of ftp / file browser web page kind of like a directory listing via web.

Comment: To build on JonH's comment: /Reports is for people, /reportserver is the service, for automated consumption, such as by other websites or .net service calls. I believe /Reports actually makes calls behind the scenes to /reportserver.